# Compatibility of commons FileUpload 1.3.3 with Struts1

Tags: java, file-upload, compatibility, struts-1

My project is working on  Struts-1 framework (using struts tags-html-el tag) with FileUpload version 1.0. We want to replace old FileUpload (v1.0) in the project with new one (v1.3.3). I simply replaced the old jar with the new one and after successful build, the functionality didn't work.

So, want to know is there any code changes I need to make to run 1.3.3 with my old code, or since all the other jars are old so this new one will not work? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If it didn't work, I'd say something would need to be changed. Since you've provided no definition of "didn't work" it's impossible to help beyond that.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for the reply. I just wanted to know is there a limitation that new FileUpload is not compatible with old Struts-1 libraries.

Comment: *shrug* Maybe, maybe not. With S1 being EOLed five years ago there won't be too many people on the Struts side looking in to issues like this. If it's not working, I'd say it's "not compatible", but that doesn't mean it can't be made to work. But for a variety of reasons, I'd move off of S1.

Comment: @DaveNewton i get your point. Thanks again for spending your time on this.